# How to allow only paypal to access my website?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want deny access to my website form all websites other than PayPal. But since they are having dynamic IP addresses which may change in later time, i need some wat to do it dynamically. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal use to provide a range of IP addresses here 
https://cms.paypal.com/fr/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_golivechecklist

Btw, They just change their developper portal, and this information is not available in the new one.
So it may be more secure to make a reverse DNS call and check on *.paypal.com
as all the ip above, are linked to this domain.